# Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString() problem

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working on a graphical listing of Roman emperors and ran into the following problem:
The birth and death dates are stored in a JSON as a string. e.g. Julius Caesar:

```
"start":"-000100-07-12"
```

If I use the Date object

`console.log(new Date(caesar.start))`

... via console.log it works:

//Date Object Thu Jul 12 -0100 00:53:28 GMT+0053 ...

but if I now want to render the object as a string with

```js
console.log(
  new Date("-000100-07-12")
  .toLocaleDateString("en", {year : "numeric", era: "short"})
);
```

console.log gives me

"101 BC" instead of "100 BC"

the problem is easily reproducable.

[I only found a similar description](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/1403794_1.html)

for a different technology.

However, the problem seems to be the same.

A fix would be to write a custom toLocaleDateString function, because getFullYear(), getMonth() work as expected.

Has anyone had similar experiences, or a solution to the problem? I guess handling dates before 1582 is a bit hooky.... maybe it has to do with the fact that there is no year 0?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years). _“maybe it has to do with the fact that there is no year 0?”_ — Yes.

Comment: ..thanks! i see, but why handles the date-object itself the datum differently, obviously there is a year zero for the Date Object ... "new Date("+000000-01-01") gives me a year zero. that is confusing, so i have to split the toLocale string for BC Dates? thats a mess..

Comment: No, `+000000` _represents_ the year 1 BCE. If you want 100 BCE, that _is_ `-000099`. Forcing `-000100` to be 100 BCE would violate the ISO 8601 standard.

Comment: See the ISO 8601 specification regarding BCE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years

Comment: Simple, use *toDateString* instead to get "Wed Jul 11 -0100". BTW, "-000100-07-12" is parsed as UTC so will represent a different date and time in different time zones (I'm east of Greenwich so it represents 11 Jul, not 12 Jul).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in **toLocaleDateString**.

But separate methods work as expected

For example

```
date.getDate(); // 12
date.getFullYear(); // -100
date.getMonth(); // 6 (getMonth() starts with 0)
```

You can get the same format with this methods.

Comment: You’re fine with `getMonth` being 0-based, so you have to add 1, But `getFullYear` can’t be offset around 0? It’s the same thing; similar to two's complement in integers. `-100` represents the year 101 BCE.

Comment: yes, thanks, thats a workaround, but its strange, that "getFullYear" can handle a year 0. But by convention there is no year 0 ... look at Sebastian Simons comment / link. So this is an avoidable Inconsistency ...

Comment: @Stefan _“but its strange, that "getFullYear" can handle a year 0”_ — That’s like saying that it’s strange that `getMonth` can handle a month 0, even though there is no month 0, and it can’t handle a month 12, even though that’s December. You have to understand that these numbers _represent_ different things, perhaps differently than what we humans are used to in our everyday lives.

Comment: yes, its also a bit of my Inconsistency but nevertheless.. for me "new Date("+000000-01-01").getFullYear()" should print -1 and not 0, the actual problem is getFullYear and not toLocaleString, isn't it?

Comment: @Stefan Ah, that’s what you mean. `getFullYear` returns what the ISO string specifies verbatim, but `getMonth` returns what the ISO string specifies _minus 1_. You’re right, and hopefully, the [Temporal API](//github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) fixes all of this. For now, I guess it’s important to know that `getFullYear` calculates the year from the number of milliseconds (which is what a Date object stores internally), then literally plus 1970. Also, there are at least no inconsistencies in arithmetic: month 4 + 2 months = month 6; year 20 − 50 years = year −30, no matter what they represent.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) standard `"-000100-07-12"` represents 12th July 101 BCE and the date appears to be being parsed correctly.

It's just that the standard doesn't match our expectations as we almost always deal with positive years.

Unfortunately I'm unable to see what the "Cause" of the linked Oracle error is so it may be the same "issue"